# Expo not connecting to device or Android emulator

Tags: android, react-native, expo

I am running Expo on a windows machine and when I run `expo start`, a mobile device nor a Android emulaor are connecting and I am getting a message "Network Response Timed Out".

However both work when I run `expo start --tunnel`.

I have switched off the Firewall and made sure that the IP address is of the correct network. Both devices are also on the same network.

Can anyone help, how to connect using the command `expo start`

Comment: Make sure that you are using the latest version of the expo app on android

Comment: Yes I have the latest version. It is not working on the emulator as well as the phone